# What do I do if I can't remember the answer to my Minecraft account security questions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to change my skin, however its showing me three security questions because it thinks I am on a new computer (even though I've been using this same computer to change my skin for the past two years).

I know the answer to 2 of the questions, but I forgot 1 of them, and I can't change the security questions.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Ask support. There's no way way around this - that's the whole concept around security questions.

Answer (score 4):

You should try getting support from Mojang itself. It is the only way a problem like this could be fixed because this is the whole purpose of having security questions, as a secondary security for your account. This is the security question section of their FAQ on their website:

https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/797301-account-security-questions

Answer (score -2):

You must contact Mojang Support, that's the only way.

Comment: This is a dupe answer.

Comment: It's a pretty straight forward answer. You cannot do anything else without guessing your security answer.

Comment: When I played SWTOR (Star Wars the Old Republic) I couldn't remember my security answer and therefore i contacted the support. Which then fixed it for me.

Comment: I also got asked serveral questions in order to know my security answer.

Comment: MxRz: I didn't say that it was complicated, I said that it was a duplicated answer. Your answer doesn't add anything to the above answer.

Comment: Ahh okey, atleast I explained it down here so the questioner can see.

Comment: We don't allow duplicated answers here, this will probably be removed.

Comment: @ardaozkal Duplicate answers within the first few day are *fine*.  It's only after that we start deleting new answers that don't add anything.

Comment: @Frank I remember someone telling me that I should allow dupes in 1-2 hours... wait, it was you!

Comment: @ardaozkal I'm pretty sure I told you within the first couple of days.  There's no reason to moderate so strictly.  They're making a good faith attempt to help on a new question.  Let it go.

Comment: No problem! Please vote my question as the best answer :)

Comment: Your answer is a single sentence. As far as quality goes, it barely passes the bar for being an answer.

Comment: I did not talk to you Frank, I talked to Ryan. And Besides he said thanks, meaning he used my answer for his needing.